# Portable source code between 386 and amd64?

Tags: x86, assembly, i386, x86-64

Goal: have a single assembler source file which will assemble both to x86 (i386) and to x86_64 (amd64)?

Is this possible, for instance with [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use conditional assemblying, you can. But don't expect to write all the code once for x86 and have it work the same on x64 or the other way around. Use [`%if and %ifdef`](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-macro-conditional.html).

You could also create some macros that would expand to different things. For example, some `RAXPTR` would expand to `EAX` or `RAX` depending on what platform you're compiling and you can use this `RAXPTR` where EAX/RAX is used as a pointer. Likewise you could create some macros `PARAM1/2/etc` that would expand to the routine params, to things like `ECX/RCX` and `EDX/RDX` for the first two parameters in the `fastcall` convention and `[EBP+some constant]/[RBP+some constant]` for the rest. Using macros in this manner can help you write mostly portable x86/x64 assembly code, but still, you can't do this without things like %if and %ifdef.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: It mostly is a superset. But only mostly because some things that are available in non-64-bit modes aren't available in 64-bit mode any more. But most importantly, your registers that you use to hold addresses of the various variables, they have to be different in 32-bit and 64-bit: E-something vs. R-something. And different calling conventions/ABIs are also getting in the way. Using macros can help here, see the updated answer.

Comment: Hm, what do you mean I couldn't without %if and %ifdef?  Do you mean those have to be inside for instance the RAXPTR macro?

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: yep. Or outside, if you like that better. It's the same as with C/C++'s #if/#ifdef.

Comment: This is exactly why someone invented the C language!

Answer (score 3):

Assembly language is by definition not portable between different CPU architectures.

Depending on the assembler you use, you can do a few things that will ease the porting part, as Alex said, like dealing with different register or instruction names with macros and conditional assembly (don't think this will make your code more readable, nor more maintainable than having two distinct files).

But on different architectures, you can't expect the same code to run fine. Especially with 32 and 64 bits architectures.

Even if you succeed in having a common code, it will certainly lack optimizations available in the different architectures.

And last, but not least, you will also have ABI issues. Calling conventions are different, even between x86 (usually CDECL - all arguments passed on the stack), and x86_64 (System V - first arguments passed on registers, then on stack).

Comment: This spells out the difficulties ahead, and +1 for that. But given I have macros for calling conventions (don't know how feasible this is) and for registers, do you think it's possible?

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: it may very well be possible. But when writing this "portable" code you'll have to constantly think of both modes/platforms and their differences and hide them behind macros. That's why it's not quite like writing one piece of code for x86 and then just reusing it as-is on x64 or the other way around.